# Python MySQL cursor - escaping percents

Tags: python

How do I escape percents in MySQL cursors in Python?

I got this query:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM foods where food_description = %s"
cursor.execute(query, ("1% milk"))
```

However, it's not working because of the % in 1% milk.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean? Are you getting an error message or is the wrong row being returned?

Comment: Could you add the error message you're seeing to your question please? I've just tried your query as above with a test table and there was no problem (I'm using Python 2.7.1 and MySQL 5.5.19 on OS X 10.6.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape it with a `\`:

```
cursor.execute(query, ("1% milk".replace('%', '\\%')))
```